# mount can't find /dev

Tags: linux, mount, startup

I get this message on my bootup screen:

```
mount: mounting udev on /dev failed: No such device
W: devtmpfs not available, falling back to tmpfs for dev
```

How do I get rid of it and what does it mean?

I can change to another virtual terminal (tty3 itd.) and login normally.

As far as I can tell the system is functioning normally otherwise after I login. 
My fstab file has lines for /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/cdrom and /

I just upgraded to ubuntu 12.04, I'm running kernel 2.6.28-15-genric.

My system is probably messed up because I followed a non-traditional upgrade path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [gentoo-wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Initramfs#devtmpfs):

> **devtmpfs**: This is a recent addition to the Linux kernel, designed to
>   offer device nodes early at bootup. To use it, enable `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS`
>   in your kernel .config.

If your kernel has this option enabled, you should have a similar output:

```
petrus@hive:/boot$ grep CONFIG_DEVTMPFS config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y
```

However, the message you have at bootup seem to indicate that your kernel hasn't this option , and thus falling back to `tmpfs` to mount `/dev`.

You can check which one you are using in `/etc/mtab`:

```
petrus@hive:~$ grep /dev /etc/mtab
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
```

If you want to mount/remount `/dev` with `devtmpfs`:

```
root@hive:~# mount -t devtmpfs none /dev
```

However, I don't know where is the system configuration regarding the choice of devtmpfs vs. tmpfs, but using `tmpfs` should cause no issue.

Comment: Thank you, there indeed was no issue related to this, upgrading the kernel to 3.5 got rid of the message