# Modprobe doesn't create nbd device

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, debian-jessie, modprobe

I am running a server with Debian 8, and after running `modprobe nbd`, the program runs just fine. However, the device is not created since `/dev/nbd0` does not exist. What should I do to get modprobe to run properly?

Comment: I have a feeling that you're comparing an old version to the system you're on.  The fact that your application can access the networked drive is already proof enough that it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a partial answer that effectively works around your problem but does not conclusively explain why the problem happened in the first place.

### Resolution

Run these commands:

```
sudo rmmod nbd 
sudo mount -t devtmpfs none /dev 
sudo modprobe nbd 
ls /dev/nbd*
```

The final command should look like this:

```
root@node51 [~]# ls /dev/nbd*
/dev/nbd0  /dev/nbd1  /dev/nbd10  /dev/nbd11  /dev/nbd12  /dev/nbd13  /dev/nbd14  /dev/nbd15  /dev/nbd2  /dev/nbd3  /dev/nbd4  /dev/nbd5  /dev/nbd6  /dev/nbd7  /dev/nbd8  /dev/nbd9
```

### Explanation

We determined [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41966/discussion-between-deltik-and-salmonkiller) that `/dev` was not being updated because it was mounted as [`tmpfs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt) instead of as [`devtmpfs`](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter07/udev.html).

You can check the second column of the following command to see if `/dev` is mounted as `tmpfs` or `devtmpfs`:

```
df -T /dev
```

Without `devtmpfs`, only the device and character files defined during the initial boot would be populated in `/dev`.  `devtmpfs` allows devices to be added and removed after boot.

It's not possible to unmount `/dev` with `umount /dev` because the special files in there are in use, but it is possible to load a fresh `devtmpfs` over the existing `/dev` mount.

`sudo mount -t devtmpfs none /dev` mounts a `devtmpfs` over the existing mount at `/dev`.

Now, when you do `sudo modprobe nbd`, the device files `/dev/nbd0` through `/dev/nbd15` get populated in `/dev`.

### Cause

I did not determine why `/dev` was mounted as `tmpfs` instead of `devtmpfs` or why [udev](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html) wasn't running.  [`devtmpfs` should have been the default.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77933)

[This answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/418269/193677) might have some leads.

Comment: Hmm. I tried doing this, and then doing `sudo rmmod nbd`. It actually removed the nbd from somewhere (I don't know where). Given that i'm running the whole system on google cloud platform, any tips on where the nbd might be?

Comment: @SalmonKiller: Do you have the stock kernel that ships with Debian 8? Does `nbd: registered device at major` show up in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't show up in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: @SalmonKiller: And what kernel are you running?

Comment: 3.16.0-4-amd64 is the kernel

Comment: @SalmonKiller: Assuming you're logging normally, the nbd kernel module is not reaching [this line in the source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/04cfac4e40b2b5dbaf8c0fc625878388a98bb9c6/drivers/block/nbd.c#L862). You should get network block devices because every failure case above that line would return an error code. Do you have folders at `/sys/block/nbd*`?

Comment: Yeah, i have those directories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41966/discussion-between-deltik-and-salmonkiller).

Comment: i had the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04, but for me it was sufficient to just run `sudo rmmod nbd; sudo modprobe nbd;` thanks